# Arduino code not working with one more instruction

Tags: c++, arduino, avr

Im looking for a reason that my arduino won't work with my code.

This code works:

```
Events *wsk;
if(Day==0)
    wsk = &Pon;
if(Day==1)
    wsk = &Wt;
```

But when i add one more instruction like:

```
Events *wsk;
if(Day==0)
    wsk = &Pon;
if(Day==1)
    wsk = &Wt;
if(Day==2)
    wsk = &Sr;
```

It's not working. Any one know why ? Arduino are not printing even a simple 'hello' serial message on setup().

Here is my full function:

```
void showMeEvents(int Day){
    String buffer="EU";
    zdarzenia *wsk;

    if(Day==0)
        wsk = &Pon;
    if(Day==1)
        wsk = &Wt;

    //not working when i add this part from here:

    if(Day==3)
        wsk = &Sr;
    if(Day==4)
        wsk = &Czw;
    if(Day==5)
        wsk = &Pia;
    if(Day==6)
        wsk = &So;

    // to here 

    buffer+=0;
    if(wsk->eventsInDay<10)
        buffer+=0;
    buffer+=wsk->eventsInDay;

    for(int i=0; i<wsk->eventsInDay; i++){
        buffer += wsk->type;
        if(wsk->eventPin[i]<10)
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->eventPin[i];
        buffer += wsk->alwaysOn[i];
        if(wsk->fromH[i]<10)
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->fromH[i];
        if(wsk->fromM[i]<10)
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->fromM[i];
        if(wsk->toH[i]<10)
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->toH[i];
        if(wsk->toM[i])
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->toM[i];
        if(wsk->toS[i]<10)
            buffer += 0;
        buffer += wsk->toS[i];
    }
    Serial.println(buffer);

}
```

Comment: Can you post the full code.

Comment: I posted my funcion. Full code is too long.

Comment: Wow Man don't try to edit my code if you don't know how it works.

Comment: I just ran it through uncrustify, the functionality was 100% unchanged. It doesn't work either way, but at least one version is readable.

Comment: Too long to post, put it on github , etc.  Tough to debug completely without the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How much ram are you using?  I've found in the past that when I approach ~95% usage of the available ram on the arduino you begin to see corruption without any warnings.  You'll have to calculate how much memory your using by hand if you're declaring within functions.

Good luck.

Comment: Could also be a power issue as well but no idea when he's not posting the entire code base.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these things don't work the way you intend them to. Try this

```
if(Day==0)
    wsk = &Pon;
else if(Day==1)
    wsk = &Wt;
else if(Day==3)
    wsk = &Sr;
else if(Day==4)
    wsk = &Czw;
else if(Day==5)
    wsk = &Pia;
else if(Day==6)
    wsk = &So;
```

or even better

```
switch(Day)
{
    case 0: { wsk = &Pon; break; }
    case 1: { wsk = &Wt; break; }
    case 3: { wsk = &Sr; break; }
    case 4: { wsk = &Czw; break; }
    case 5: { wsk = &Pia; break; }
    case 6: { wsk = &So; break; }
    default: break;
}
```

Comment: I was trying to change if to switch but it didnt work. I got the solution and posted below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This does not compile. Remove the empty if 3-6 and start using blocks {} with your ifs.

```
if(Day==0)
    wsk = &Pon;
if(Day==1)
    wsk = &Wt;
if(Day==3)
if(Day==4)
if(Day==5)
if(Day==6)
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for replys. My problem was caused by too much RAM usage by ethercard lib. I just used other library for enc28j60 module and it's working ! :).

Sry for language mistakes.